# Sonarlint installed on eclipse Kepler but not found

Tags: java, eclipse, sonar-runner, eclipse-kepler, sonarlint

I have installed SonarLint version 2.2.0 on Eclipse Kepler via Market Place.
But when i go to Project-> Properties, there i am not able to find any Sonar Option. Also in Window -> Show View, No Sonar view option is found.

While installing SonarLint, no error occurred.

1.Is eclipse Kepler supports SonarLint?
2.After Installation, Any more setting to be done to make SonarLint visible?

Regards
Gaurav

Comment: Did U enabled it on project ???

Comment: @SkorpEN, how to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I just upgraded my java to 1.7 and now it's OK

```
apt-get install java7-sdk
update-alternative --config java and choose java7
```

restart eclipse

But impossible to get issues in my eclipse project... I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/:
SonarLint is free, open source, and available in the Eclipse Marketplace. Note that it requires Java 8 to run.

So you have to ensure that eclipse (the IDE, not your project!) is started with jdk8.